# Proper way to detect if a ClientObject property is already retrieved/initialized

Tags: c#, sharepoint, csom

If you're using the Client Object Model from SharePoint and access properties which haven't been initialized or already retrieved by an

```
Context.Load(property); 
Context.ExecuteQuery();
```

you get for example a:

> Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.PropertyOrFieldNotInitializedException

or

> The collection has not been initialized. It has not been requests or
>   the request has not been executed.

Exception.

Is there any proper way to check before accessing these properties if they are already initialized/retrieved? Without a Try/Catch approach. I don`t like that one's.

I want to check before a Exception has been thrown and handle it.

I already checked the

[IsObjectPropertyInstantiated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.clientobject.isobjectpropertyinstantiated(v=office.15).aspx)

[IsPropertyAvailable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.clientobject.ispropertyavailable(v=office.15).ASPX)

Methods but they don't help really. `IsPropertyAvaiable` only checks scalar properties and won't give a result on for example `Web.Lists` and `IsObjectPropertyInstantiated` returns true for `Web.Lists` although `Web.Lists` was not initialized.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I would say your question is already contains the correct answer to some extent.

In order to determine whether client object property is loaded or not the following methods are available:

- [ClientObject.IsPropertyAvailable method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.clientobject.ispropertyavailable(v=office.15).ASPX) method indicates whether
  the specified **scalar** property has been retrieved or set
- [ClientObject.IsObjectPropertyInstantiated method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.clientobject.isobjectpropertyinstantiated(v=office.15).aspx) indicates
  whether the specified property of the client object is instantiated

### Tests

Test case 1: load scalar property only

```
ctx.Load(ctx.Web, w => w.Title);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
//Results:
ctx.Web.IsObjectPropertyInstantiated("Lists")  False
ctx.Web.IsPropertyAvailable("Title")    True
```

Test case 2: load composite property only

```
ctx.Load(ctx.Web, w => w.Lists);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
//Results:
ctx.Web.IsObjectPropertyInstantiated("Lists")  True
ctx.Web.IsPropertyAvailable("Title")    False
```

Test case 3: load both scalar and composite properties

```
ctx.Load(ctx.Web, w=>w.Lists,w=>w.Title);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
//Results
ctx.Web.IsObjectPropertyInstantiated("Lists")  True
ctx.Web.IsPropertyAvailable("Title")    True
```

---

---

### How to dynamically determine whether client object property is loaded or not?

Since [ClientObject.IsPropertyAvailable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.clientobject.ispropertyavailable(v=office.15).ASPX) and [ClientObject.IsObjectPropertyInstantiated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.clientobject.isobjectpropertyinstantiated(v=office.15).aspx) methods expect the property name to be specified as a string value and that could lead to typos, I usually prefer the following [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx):

```
public static class ClientObjectExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Determines whether Client Object property is loaded
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="clientObject"></param>
    /// <param name="property"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static bool IsPropertyAvailableOrInstantiated<T>(this T clientObject, Expression<Func<T, object>> property)
        where T : ClientObject
    {
        var expression = (MemberExpression)property.Body;
        var propName = expression.Member.Name;
        var isCollection = typeof(ClientObjectCollection).IsAssignableFrom(property.Body.Type);
        return isCollection ? clientObject.IsObjectPropertyInstantiated(propName) : clientObject.IsPropertyAvailable(propName);
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
using (var ctx = new ClientContext(webUri))
{

     ctx.Load(ctx.Web, w => w.Lists, w => w.Title);
     ctx.ExecuteQuery();


     if (ctx.Web.IsPropertyAvailableOrInstantiated(w => w.Title))
     {
         //...
     }

     if (ctx.Web.IsPropertyAvailableOrInstantiated(w => w.Lists))
     {
         //...
     }
}
```

Comment: The question mentions that IsObjectPropertyInstantiated returns true even if Lists was not really initialized. Did you check it?

Comment: Yep, at least it returns false when Lists property is not requested (test case 1). Tested against SharePoint 2013

Comment: that's a nice little extension method, which is working like a charm!

Comment: OfficeDev PnP now contains `EnsureProperty` and `EnsureProperties` methods.

Comment: Starting c# 6 you can also use nameof keyword

Answer (score 1):

The tests provided by Vadim Gremyachev only cover one half of the scenarios - where you use ctx.Load. But when you use ctx.LoadQuery the result changes:

```
var query = from lst in ctx.Web.Lists where lst.Title == "SomeList" select lst;
var lists = ctx.LoadQuery(query);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
ctx.Web.IsObjectPropertyInstantiated("Lists") -> True
ctx.Web.Lists.ServerObjectIsNull -> False
ctx.Web.Lists.Count -> CollectionNotInitializedException
```

So once the LoadQuery has been called on a collection, you can no longer see if the collection is actually available.

Only way in this case is to detect that the exception occurs.

Answer (score 1):

OK, this is getting more and more complicated especially with SharePoint Online where results of Load and Execute methods may be incomplete even without thrown exceptions. However, below is what I collected from this and other threads combined to a LoadAndExecute method that can be a subclass extension to the ClientContext class or be converted to a static extension class. For a new client object, the object and its properties are loaded in one operation but the result is checked separately for each property. For an existing client object, only missing properties are loaded in separate operations which may consume network resources unnecessarily. So the method doesn't only check which properties are not initialized but tries to retrieve the missing ones, too. In addition, there is another topic of avoiding being throttled by overriding the Execute method of the ClientContext, but that is not included here:

```
/// <summary>
/// An extended ClientContext to avoid getting throttled.
/// </summary>
public partial class OnlineContext : ClientContext
{
    /// <inheritdoc />
    public OnlineContext(string webFullUrl, int retryCount = 0, int delay = 0)
        : base(webFullUrl)
    {
        RetryCount = retryCount;
        Delay = delay;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The retry count.
    /// </summary>
    public int RetryCount { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The delay between attempts in seconds.
    /// </summary>
    public int Delay { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Loads and executes the specified client object properties.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">the object type.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="clientObject">the object.</param>
    /// <param name="properties">the properties.</param>
    /// <returns>true if all available, false otherwise.</returns>
    public bool LoadAndExecute<T>(T clientObject, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] properties)
        where T : ClientObject
    {
        int retryAttempts = 0;
        int backoffInterval = Math.Max(Delay, 1);

        bool retry;
        bool available;
        do
        {
            if (clientObject is ClientObjectCollection)
            {
                // Note that Server Object can be null for collections!
                ClientObjectCollection coc = (ClientObjectCollection) (ClientObject) clientObject;
                if (!coc.ServerObjectIsNull.HasValue || !coc.ServerObjectIsNull.Value)
                {
                    available = coc.AreItemsAvailable;
                }
                else
                {
                    available = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            else if (clientObject.ServerObjectIsNull.HasValue)
            {
                available = !clientObject.ServerObjectIsNull.Value;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                available = false;
            }

            if (!available && retryAttempts++ <= RetryCount)
            {
                if (retryAttempts > 1)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(backoffInterval * 1000);
                    backoffInterval *= 2;
                }

                Load(clientObject, properties);
                ExecuteQuery();
                retry = true;
            }
            else
            {
                retry = false;
            }
        } while (retry);

        if (available)
        {
            if (properties != null && properties.Length > 0)
            {
                foreach (Expression<Func<T, object>> property in properties)
                {
                    if (!LoadAndExecuteProperty(clientObject, property, retryAttempts > 0))
                    {
                        available = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return available;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Loads and executes the specified client object property.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">the object type.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="clientObject">the object.</param>
    /// <param name="property">the property.</param>
    /// <param name="loaded">true, if the client object was already loaded and executed at least once.</param>
    /// <returns>true if available, false otherwise.</returns>
    private bool LoadAndExecuteProperty<T>(T clientObject, Expression<Func<T, object>> property, bool loaded = false)
        where T : ClientObject
    {
        string propertyName;
        bool isObject;
        bool isCollection;
        Func<T, object> func;
        Expression expression = property.Body;
        if (expression is MemberExpression)
        {
            // Member expression, check its type to select correct property test.
            propertyName = ((MemberExpression) expression).Member.Name;
            isObject = typeof(ClientObject).IsAssignableFrom(property.Body.Type);
            isCollection = isObject
                ? typeof(ClientObjectCollection).IsAssignableFrom(property.Body.Type)
                : false;
            func = isObject ? property.Compile() : null;
        }
        else if (!loaded)
        {
            // Unary expression or alike, test by invoking its function.
            propertyName = null;
            isObject = false;
            isCollection = false;
            func = property.Compile();
        }
        else
        {
            // Unary expression and alike should be available if just loaded.
            return true;
        }

        int retryAttempts = 0;
        int backoffInterval = Math.Max(Delay, 1);

        bool retry;
        bool available;
        do
        {
            if (isObject)
            {
                if (clientObject.IsObjectPropertyInstantiated(propertyName))
                {
                    ClientObject co = (ClientObject) func.Invoke(clientObject);
                    if (isCollection)
                    {
                        ClientObjectCollection coc = (ClientObjectCollection) co;
                        if (!coc.ServerObjectIsNull.HasValue || !coc.ServerObjectIsNull.Value)
                        {
                            available = coc.AreItemsAvailable;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            available = false;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    else if (co.ServerObjectIsNull.HasValue)
                    {
                        available = !co.ServerObjectIsNull.Value;
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        available = false;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    available = false;
                }
            }
            else if (propertyName != null)
            {
                available = clientObject.IsPropertyAvailable(propertyName);
            }
            else if (func != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    func.Invoke(clientObject);
                    available = true;
                }
                catch (PropertyOrFieldNotInitializedException)
                {
                    available = false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                available = true; // ?
            }

            if (!available && retryAttempts++ <= RetryCount)
            {
                if (retryAttempts > 1)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(backoffInterval * 1000);
                    backoffInterval *= 2;
                }

                Load(clientObject, property);
                ExecuteQuery();
                retry = true;
            }
            else
            {
                retry = false;
            }
        } while (retry);
        return available;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea of using a extension is great, but only works fine with lists. The extension may choose between "object" and "scalar" properties. I think than the extension will be better this way:

```
public static bool IsPropertyAvailableOrInstantiated<T>(this T clientObject, Expression<Func<T, object>> property)
    where T : ClientObject
{
    var expression = (MemberExpression)property.Body;
    var propName = expression.Member.Name;
    var isObject = typeof(ClientObject).IsAssignableFrom(property.Body.Type); // test with ClientObject instead of ClientObjectList
    return isObject ? clientObject.IsObjectPropertyInstantiated(propName) : clientObject.IsPropertyAvailable(propName);
}
```